# Dojo Uploader HTML5 plugin vs iFrame plugin

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm looking at using dojox/form/Uploader in Dojo 1.7.5.

I want to have multiple file upload without using Flash in modern browsers, if IE doesn't support it, it can just have single upload. From the documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/form/Uploader.html), it looks like if you require the iFrame plugin, it will use an iFrame for IE and the HTML5 plugin for other browsers.

This seems to be the case. However, the issue is that the iFrame needs the JSON response from the server wrapped in textarea HTML tags. These tags cause the HTML5 plugin to fail at line 168 on this.onComplete(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText.replace(/^{}&&/,'')));
because the responsetext is not valid JSON.

Why is there this seeming incompatibility? Is there any way to get the behavior I want without writing my own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a solution, i have one.

You have to send the message like that:

```
Dim msg = "<textarea>'{" + Chr(34) + "name" + Chr(34) + ":" + Chr(34) + fileName + Chr(34) + "," + Chr(34) + "file" + Chr(34) + ":" + Chr(34) + returnData.Item1 + Chr(34) + "," + Chr(34) + "type" + Chr(34) + ":" + Chr(34) +   returnData.Item3 + Chr(34) + "}'</textarea>"
Dim response = Request.CreateResponse(Of String)(HttpStatusCode.Created, msg)
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")
Return response
```

On the client side you have to change the iframe.js to work with that response.

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
```

and in function "handleResponse":

```
// 'json' and 'javascript' and 'text'
response.text = doc.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value; // text
response.text = eval(replaceAll(response.text, "\\", ""));
```

This is not a good solution but i could not find another one, i aslo made a post because of that:
[ASP.NET webAPI <--> Dojo uploader response format is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218016/asp-net-webapi-dojo-uploader-response-format-is-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself, here is the server side solution:

```
json = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(json)
Dim msg = "<textarea>" + json + "</textarea>"
```

The dojo file uploader now parses the response correctly.